# What are the Magento 2 Grunt commands? From deployment?

Tags: magento2, grunt

I am developing on Magento 2 EE and I have just setup up my local machine. I notice that after using Composer I can now see Magento 2 EE.

So I ran the command grunt deploy and this basically appeared that it went through a list of CSS LESS and JS files and ran the Grunt. If I was a on live SSH box and I ran grunt deploy will this take the server down or just simply update the files and minify them?

My plan is:

Develop a theme locally with all SASS/LESS and JS files in RequireJS
Copy those files and replace them to live.
Then run grunt deploy on live box.

I take it this is the way it works?

Answer (score 2):

So the Magento 2 grunt commands are the following:

- `grunt clean:<theme>` : Removes the theme related static files in the `pub/static` and `var` directories.
- `grunt exec:<theme>` : Republishes symlinks to the source files to the `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>` directory.
- `grunt less:<theme>` : Compiles `.css` files using the symlinks published in the `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<locale>` directory
- `grunt watch` : Tracks the changes in the source files, recompiles `.css` files, and reloads the page in the browser pages (you need to have LiveReload installed for you browser)

More informations can be found at the following links:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_prereq
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html#server-side-grunt

Regarding a deploy command, the only one I'm aware of is to clean CSS cache or refresh LESS files: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`